# How to create a form to edit an object and its child-objects?

Tags: hibernate, jsp, jquery, webforms, struts2

Im using Struts2 and Hibernate, trying to create a simple form to edit an object and all its children (one-to-many).

I've attached [an image](http://www.dahlsdata.no/problem.png) to show what im trying to do.

Does anyone have any idea/examples of how I can do this the easiest way? I just cannot understand how to create this kind of form. I've looked for answers for 2 days now, without getting anywhere.

I have been able to create the simple person-form and persisting it, and I have also been able to display a list of the pets in the form, but I have not come any closer to a solution as to how to create new pets and edit them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use ajax; this way adding/editing a pet can be persisted immediately and the owner can be persisted when submitting the form. The other solution would be to add all the information into the request when submitting the form and figuring out in your Action class what to do; it is feasible but will require some thinking and javascript (although also for the ajax solution you will require this).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know of any examples where some similar functionality is used?

Comment: Yes, but not with with struts; I've done something similar with spring-mvc and DWR (for ajax).

Answer (score 0):

As you are using struts 2 the i would suggest you to go the struts2 jquery pluginits the best thing you want as per your image requirment.

[Visit it](http://www.weinfreund.de/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action)

Agoing to the page go to grid tab.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The grid thing seems fine. I can use it, but I could also use something waaaaay simpler. I would just like the most simple solution to what im trying to do. No need for fancy grid-systems, sorting and all that mumbo jumbo. Just how to easy implement add-edit-delete on the childlist in the form. With or without page-refresh, i really dont care. I just cant wrap my head around how to work with childlist without any examples...